# Laravel 8 subfolder Controller

Tags: laravel, routes, controller, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I created folder in Controller. But Laravel is giving

`Target class [App\Http\Controllers\SAIDE\SaideMerchantController] does not exist.`

error

-->Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\SAIDE;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;


class SaideMerchantController extends Controller
{
  
    
    public function home()
    {
      return view('backoffice.saide.maindashboard');
    }

      Route::get('/maindashboard','SAIDE\SaideMerchantController@home');
}
```

-->end controller

How to use controller in Folder ?

Comment: Did you change the controller's namespace to `App\Http\Controllers\SAIDE`?

Comment: please include the controller code and where the controller file is saved

Comment: Did you try by referencing the full namesapce in the route? ``Route::get('/maindashboard','App\Http\Controllers\SAIDE\SaideMerchantController@home');``

Answer (score 0):

We don't see a complete route file, but try the change the get method to

`Rouge::get('/mainboard', [App\Http\Controllers\SAID\SaidMerchantController::class, 'home']);`

Check out Laravel documentation for version 8 routing
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing

Comment: I added this in Controller. And solve my problem.

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;